# PyQt5 button animation

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a PyQt application with stylesheet formatted widgets. The buttons have a css change (clicked) function on them, like this:

CSS

[image]

But I would like to achieve this:

animated

[image]

Is there a way to animate stylesheet as mentioned above, or I have to manipulate the button's paint event, or something else?
Could you give some help, please?!

Answer (score 2):

You might need to have something like this...

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSize

class PB(QtGui.QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtGui.QPushButton.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):

        if event.pos().x()>self.width()-10 or event.pos().y()>self.height()-10\
                    or event.pos().x() < 10 or event.pos().y()< 10:
            bmp = QtGui.QIcon('/tmp/1.png')
            self.setIcon(bmp)

        else:
            bmp = QtGui.QIcon('/tmp/2.png')
            self.setIcon(bmp)
        self.setIconSize(QSize(200,200))
        return QtGui.QPushButton.mouseMoveEvent(self, event)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w  = QtGui.QWidget()
    b = PB()
    b.setParent(w)
    b.setGeometry(50,50,200,200)
    w.resize(300,300)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: 1.png][image: 2.png]
Attached images used.

Comment: Thank you, but I want to animate the button's click event.
I have the two stylesheet schemes, and don't know how to make the transition animation between them like the "animated" gif.